# Kubernetes - how to map docker run command-line parameters to kubectl command line

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, kubernetes

I need to run this Docker command in Kubernetes:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 sagemath/sagemath sage -notebook
```

I can map everything across except "-notebook" - does anyone know how to do that?

Here is what I have so far, and of course it doesn't work since "-notebook" is not translated over to kubectl correctly:

```
kubectl run --image=sagemath/sagemath sage --port=8080 --type=LoadBalancer -notebook
```

Comment: `-notebook` is not an argument to docker or kubectl, but to `sage`.

Comment: Yes - but how do I implement that in kubectl - that is the question.  The docker command line above does work

Comment: The command you want to run goes at the end, just like before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you define pod spec for your sage you can define both `command` and an `args` array, so for you it would be like

```
command: sage
args:
- -notebook
```

for launching with `kubectl run`

```
Usage:
  kubectl run NAME --image=image [--env="key=value"] [--port=port] [--replicas=replicas] [--dry-run=bool] [--overrides=inline-json] [--command] -- [COMMAND] [args...] [options]
```

so try running with `--` delimiter : `kubectl run --image=sagemath/sagemath --port=8080 --type=LoadBalancer -- sage -notebook`

Comment: Thanks.  Does this mean that I can't do it via command line only (have to create the pod spec)?

Comment: updated with `run` reference

Answer (score 1):

`--` does the trick. It means that kubectl wouldn't parse as kubectl arguments the following strings that start with `-`

So you run that container executing:

```
kubectl run --image=sagemath/sagemath --port=8080 sage -- -notebook
```

And if you want a public IP on GKE, you should expose the container executing:

```
kubectl expose deploy sage --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

You can get the public IP running `kubectl get service` in the row `sage` at the column EXTERNAL-IP

Answer (score 0):

```
command: sage notebook
args:
```

For such cases

```
k run --image=sagemath/sagemath --port=8080 --command=true -- sage notebook
```

--command=false
If true and extra arguments are present, use them as the 'command' field in the container, rather than the 'args' field which is the default.